# How to select span within a dynamically generated button?

Tags: javascript, html

Problem:
How to update the innerHtml of a span within a dynamically generated button using only JavaScript?

I'm building a 'like' feature (think social media) where users can like/unlike posts, but I can't figure out how to select the value of the specific span the user clicks on. I've been only able to find jQuery solutions using `.find('span')`

```js
const htmlBtn = `<button class="count"><span>0</span></button>`;

const create = document.getElementById("create");
create.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const container = document.createElement("div");
  container.className = "container";

  container.innerHTML = htmlBtn;
  document.getElementById("app").append(container);
});

const app = document.getElementById("app");
app.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const btn = e.target;
  /*
  each time someone click nth button, span within nth button increments by 1
  
  let count = document.querySelector("span").innerHTML;
  count++;
  document.querySelector("span").innerHTML = count;
  */
});
```

```html
<button id="create">Create</button>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Expected outcome:
User clicks the button to increment the span of only that button by 1.

Comment: when you create the span give it an id

Comment: `e.target.children[0].innerHTML = parseInt(e.target.children[0].innerHTML) + 1`

Comment: Create `span` then use `DOMContentLoaded` function to select it. Otherwise element will be created after selection

Comment: the above code works, but as @DCR noted, it would be definitely cleaner (and more clear) if you added a unique ID and a specific class to each span

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e.target.children` will give you an array of all the children of `button` and the 0th index of the array should be your `span` element which you can then edit normally using the `innerHTML` method.

In your case,

```js
let count = parseInt(e.target.children[0].innerHTML);
e.target.children[0].innerHTML = count + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const container = document.createElement("div");
  container.className = "container";

  container.innerHTML = htmlBtn;
  document.getElementById("app").append(container);

  container.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const value = +e.target.innerHTML;
    e.target.innerHTML = (value + 1).toString();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The methods `querySelector()` and `querySelectorAll()` can be called on a specific parent element, similar to `find()` in jQuery.

Make sure to use `e.currentTarget` and not `e.target` in the event listener, in order to refer to the element that handles the event and not to any child element.

**Example** - click any of numbers to increment.

```js
function clickToIncrement(e) {
  const innerSpan = e.currentTarget.querySelector('span');
  
  if (innerSpan) {
    innerSpan.textContent++;
  }
}

document.getElementById('div1').addEventListener('click', clickToIncrement);
document.getElementById('div2').addEventListener('click', clickToIncrement);
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <span>0</span>
</div>
<div id="div2">
  <span>0</span>
</div>
```